# What is the probability that Carlos and Diego are placed in the same room?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I just wrote my data exam and I didn’t understand the following question:

> Given $10$ people are randomly placed in $5$ double hotel rooms, what are the odds that $2$ friends Carlos and Diego are placed in the same room?

My approach to the problem was to solve for all possible outcomes by taking the sum of $10c2+8c2+6c2+4c2+2c2$ which is $9c5$ then solving for the number of outcomes in which they are together which is $8c2+6c2+4c2+2c2$ then we placed one over the other to get $1/45$, which is not the correct answer

Comment: You shouldn't be adding.

Comment: Much simpler:  Carlos has to be paired with somebody, and each of the other $9$ is equally likely to be his roommate.

Comment: @lulu turns out according to my teacher and the online question bank, my answer (1/45) was the correct answer. The explanation was that there are 5 good out comes and 5*10c2 possible combinations making it 1/10c2

Comment: Sorry, that explanation does not make any sense.  If you can program at all, run a simulation and check.

Comment: There are far more than $5$ good outcomes.  Once C and D are paired up we still can pair the others up in multiple ways.

Comment: To be sure:  if you transcribed the problem incorrectly then of course the answer might be different.  If, say, we imagined that the rooms are numbered and that the question read "Find the probability that $C$ and $D$ are both assigned to room $1$." then the answer would indeed be $\frac 1{45}$.  Specifying the room changes a lot,  But of course that isn't the way the question currently reads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it along the lines you started:  There are $$\binom {10}2\times \binom 82\times \binom 62\times \binom 42$$  ways to assign the people to $5$ numbered rooms with no restriction.

If we pair Carlos and Diego up we must first choose a room for them, $5$ choices, and then assign the others.  Thus there are $$5\times \binom 82\times \binom 62\times \binom 42$$

ways to assign the people to rooms such that $C$ and $D$ are together.

The ratio is $$\frac 5{\binom {10}2}=\frac 5{45}=\frac 19$$

More simply:  Carlos must be paired with someone, and each of the other $9$ is equally likely to be his roommate, so the answer is $\frac 19$.

Comment: How would your solution change if the rooms were not numbered?

Comment: It wouldn't.  Carlos still needs to be paired with someone, and each of the other $9$ is still equally likely to be his roommate.